# $2n$ knights around a table with namecards, is it possible that for every rotation there is exactly one person with a correct namecard?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, puzzle, pigeonhole-principle

I need help with the following puzzle:

Consider a round table which hosts $2n$ knights. At each seat, there is a namecard of one knight. The knights don't necessarily sit in front of their own namecard. Prove that we can rotate the table such that at least 2 knights sit in front of their own nameplate.

Using the pigeon hole principle, it's quite easy to see that this is equivalent with:

- Proving that there exists a rotation where no knights sit in front of their own namecard.
- Proving that it is impossible that in every rotation, exactly one knight sits in front of his own namecard.

After going over some examples, I noted that if for knight number $k$, the angle needed to get this knight in front of his nameplate is $\frac{a_k \pi}{n}$, then the sum $a_1 + ... + a_{2n}$ is a multiple of n. If one could prove this, then this would solve the problem: if in every rotation, there is exactly one person sitting in front of his namecard, then
$$a_1 + .. . + a_{2n} = 0+1+...+ 
(2n-1) = n(2n - 1),$$
which is not a multiple of $2n$.

Another method is also welcome of course. Thank you in advance!

Comment: To clarify, what are you looking for? $\quad$ You've shared the standard solution to this puzzle. It can also be interpreted as an "expected value argument".

Comment: Also, being very nitpicky about the presentation, you don't need the preamble of PHP. Your solution directly shows that the set of $ a_i $ contains duplicates, hence we could rotate by $-a_I$ to get the duplicate knights.

Comment: I did not solve the puzzle since I did not prove yet that $a_1+...+a_{2n}$ is a multiple of $2n$. I just observed this phenomenon in examples.

Comment: Ah, then just FYI that you had all of the elements needed to prove the problem, and just needed to put it together. I glossed over your "if one could prove this" and treated it as "based on what we've been discussing, the following holds".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $1,2,..,,2n$ be the numbers of the knights clockwise. Let $a_i$ be the number of places we have to rotate a table counter-clockwise so that $i$-th knight sits in front of his namecard.

If $a_i=a_j$ for some $i\neq j$ then we’re done. Otherwise $$\sum a_i = 0+1+2+…+(2n-1)=n\cdot(2n-1).$$

Note that $i+a_i$ or $i+a_i-2n$ is the number of place where the namecard of the $i$-th knight is. It means that for some integer $k$ holds $$\sum (i+a_i)=1+2+…+2n+(2n)\cdot k.$$

So $$\sum a_i=(2n)\cdot k=n\cdot(2k).$$

But $n\cdot(2n-1)= n\cdot(2k)$ never holds. Contradiction.

Comment: You can simply the solution by stating that you're working in modulo $2n$. EG that gets rid of the "not necessarily true" part.

Comment: I think you meant $i - a_i \mod 2n$ is the number of the knight sitting g at the nameplate of knight $i$

Comment: @Steve You’re right, but I’ve just changed the direction of table rotation from clockwise to counter-clockwise instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to present the same argument (I solved it like this when I saw it).

---

Label the cards around the table in clockwise order as $0,1,2 \ldots 2n-1$ and name the knights with their respective numbers. Let $f: \Bbb Z/(2n)\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/(2n)\Bbb Z$ be such that $f(k)$ is the position (i.e., the name card at his current position) of knight $k$.

Define $g: \Bbb Z/(2n)\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/(2n)\Bbb Z$ as $g(k) = (f(k) - k) \text{ mod } 2n$. FTSOC assume that $g$ is injective (and hence, bijective).

Next, note that the orbit of $f(k)$ is a cycle of length $l_k$, where $1\le l_k \le 2n$. Then

$$f(0) - 0 = g(0)$$
$$f^2(0) - f(0) = g(f(0))$$
$$\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\cdot$$
$$f^{l_0}(0) - f^{l_0-1}(0) = g(f^{l_0-1}(0))$$
Since $g$ is injective, the values in the RHS's must be distinct. Sum this, and note the LHS telescopes to give $0$, so the RHS must be $0 \text{ mod } 2n$. Do this for all the cycles, to get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} k \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} g(k) \equiv 0 \pmod{2n}$$
a contradiction.

---

The uselessly technical terminology aside, note that the orbits of $f$ will always have such properties; it is the injectivity of $g$ that allows us to achieve a contradiction, and as such, all other methods must boil down to the injectivity of $g$.