# Strategy for Ensuring No Participant Ends Up With Their Own Item in a Circular Distribution

Tags: combinatorics

> A group of n friends get together for a cheese tasting where each member of the group brings a cheese taster. Before starting, the friends sit at a round table with n seats and the cheese samples are distributed randomly to everyone. Every member of the group receives one and only one taster. Assume someone has received their own cheese to taste, is there a rotation of the samples that can fix that? (That is, is it possible to rotate the samples around the table so that nobody receives their own cheese taster?)

My initial thought was to simply rotate all the cheese samples one seat to the left or right until eventually everyone doesn't have their own cheese. However, this doesn't seem like the correct and foolproof method. I tried thinking about more complex rotation schemes or even a systematic way to ensure a derangement. Despite this, I find myself stuck on how to conceptualise a foolproof method that guarantees no one receives their own cheese sample, regardless of the initial distribution.

Is there a mathematical approach or algorithm that ensures a successful redistribution of items in such a way that no item ends up with its original owner, specifically in a circular arrangement? Any insights or suggestions on how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's an algorithm that has nothing to do with the circular arrangement. If that matters, clarify the question to tell us what redistributions are allowed. If there are an even number who have their own then swap in pairs. If there are an odd number, swap pairs until just one is left. That person swaps with anyone else.

Comment: I believe the only way we can redistribute the cheese is through a kind of rotation, meaning each person passes their cheese to someone else in a specific direction. Given that everyone is seated around a circular table, this process involves you passing your cheese to the individual seated directly to your left or right. Consequently, the person seated to your right/left (respectively) will pass their cheese to you.

Comment: I think this is not possible because if one considers the case of 3 people in the arrangement where the first person gets their own cheese, the second person gets the third person's cheese and the last person gets the second person's cheese. Then, any form of rotation will lead to someone having their own cheese.

Comment: Heads up that for odd $n$, it's not always possible to guarantee this. Think about how to generalize your $n = 3$ example. For even $n$, we can come up with an argument (and that's a "well-known" problem, EG See this post from earlier [today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872215/2n-knights-around-a-table-with-namecards-is-it-possible-that-for-every-rotati)).

Comment: Hello @CalvinLin, I believe I've devised a strategy for cases where 
n is odd. Essentially, we can allow the person in the center to keep their own cheese while reversing the order of the cheese distribution for everyone else. For example, a sequence like 12345 would become 54321, and 1234567 would transform into 7654321, etc. With this approach, regardless of the rotation, there will always be one person who ends up with their own cheese. Though, I'm a bit stumped on the even cases and I'd really appreciate if you could give hints or link the problem itself.

Comment: Did you read the post that I linked to? It explicitly says "Proving that there exists a rotation where no knights sit in front of their own namecard."

Comment: Oh sorry, that post you linked didn't show up until just now.